# Axios get request gets all the data, unless I set state in the .then method in which case the data is erratic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, es6-promise

So I'm having an issue in my React code. I have a parent component that renders a child component, which is a container with a few banner images. In the parent component (let's call it `Parent`), I make an axios GET request to my API to fetch the data I need to pass as props to `Child`.

I make this call inside the `Parent`'s `componentDidMount()`, which also houses some more separate axios calls.

```
axios.get(`${config.host.api}/banners`).then(res => {
    let offban = res.data.trend;
    console.log(offban)
    this.setState({ mainOfferBanner: offban });
});
```

Here's where my problem lies: the `console.log(offban)` part prints my array correctly with 4 elements when I comment out the `this.setState({ banner: offban })` part. However, my `Child` component obviously does not work because I have no way of passing the data to the `Child` component. However, when I uncomment the `this.setState({ mainOfferBanner: offban })` part, I get something like this (can't post images yet):

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {...}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

As you can see, the console says that the array is of length 4, but on expanding there is just one of my 4 items from the GET request, as well as the inner length property which says 1.

The `Child`'s render function gets called multiple times and there is only one item in the array which is in the snippet above, even though the console shows that the array has 4 elements. This causes only one of the 4 banners to be shown on the website. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

I'm using React 15.5.4 and Axios 0.16.1

EDIT: Here's my entire `Parent`'s `componentDidMount()`:

```
componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`${config.host.gen}/products/trending`)
            .then(res => {
                const products = res.data.trending;
                const deals = res.data.deals;
                this.setState({products, deals});
            });


        axios.get(`${config.host.gen}/banners/mh/1`)
            .then(res => {
                const banners = res.data;
                this.setState({banners});
            });

        axios.get(`${config.host.api}/products/offer/card_main`)
            .then(res => {
                let offban = res.data.trend;
                console.log(offban)
                this.setState({ mainOfferBanner: offban });
            });

        this.fetchBanner();
    }
```

And the `Parent`'s `render` function:

```
render() {
    const {..., mainOfferBanner} = this.state
    return (
        ...
        <Child mainOffer={mainOfferBanner} />
        ...
    )
}
```

And the `Child` component looks like:

```
class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        if (this.props.mainOffer && this.props.mainOffer.length > 0) {
            return (
                <div>
                    {this.props.mainOffer.map((item, idx) => {
                        return (
                            <div>
                                <img src={item.img_hash} />
                            </div>
                        )
                     })}
                </div>
        } else {
            return null;
        }
     }
}
```

This ends up showing only 1 image since there is just 1 item in the array, even though the postman request returns 4 items like intended. And, removing the `this.setState({ mainOfferBanner: offban });` causes the `console.log` to print out all 4 items in an array

Comment: `which also houses some more separate axios calls.` please show us the whole code.

Comment: I'm a bit confused; the snippet you show first is unrelated to what you pass to `<Child />`. Calling `setState` cannot change what `console.log` shows. I don't understand what you mean by "you have no way to pass the data to the child", that's precisely what you're doing. Also, https://vasanthk.gitbooks.io/react-bits/anti-patterns/04.setState-in-componentWillMount.html.

Comment: I understand that calling `setState` does not affect what `console.log` shows, but that's precisely what's happening. And I made an error in my post: I made all axios calls in `componentDidMount`, not `componentWillMount`. When I have setState uncommented, the `console.log` data seems to be erratic, never showing the expected 4 data items. However, commenting it out results in all data being correctly outputted to the console @DaveNewton

Comment: I have seen a similar error when you try and merge an array into an object. The array keys `'0'` as object keys. `console.log` might not display this as you expect. Try `this.setState({ mainOfferBanner: offban.slice(0) })` to ensure you're referencing a native array.

Comment: Keep in mind that was the browser shows in a `console.log` is not necessarily what's there when the console.log is executed--different browsers handle this in different ways. It's more likely you're seeing a browser implementation issue rather than impossible behavior.