# Axios get method response in React cannot be displayed getting data from firebase as an array in my blog application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, axios

I wonder if someone could help me. I have read many StackOverflow's answers around this and other great articles like [this one](https://alligator.io/react/axios-react/) and I couldn't implement an answer yet.

I have got a simple blog app in React. I have a form to submit the data and I have separate post and posts component as well. I can actually send data to my firebase database. I also get the response in GET method but I cannot show the response as I need it to be. I need an array of posts which each post has a title and content so that I can send its data to my Post component. But I always get an error like( map cannot be used on the response) and I actually cannot get an array out of my database. I even wonder if I am sending data in the right format. Please check my code below and help me out. Thanks.

```
// The individual post component
const Post = props => (
    <article className="post">
        <h2 className="post-title">{props.title}</h2>
        <hr />
        <p className="post-content">{props.content}</p>
    </article>
);

// The form component to be written later

class Forms extends React.Component {}

// The posts loop component

class Posts extends React.Component {
    state = {
        posts: null,
        post: {
            title: "",
            content: ""
        }
        // error:false
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        // const posts = this.state.posts;
        axios
            .get("firebaseURL/posts.json")
            .then(response => {
                const updatedPosts = response.data;
                // const updatedPosts = Array.from(response.data).map(post => {
                //  return{
                //      ...post
                //  }
                // });
                this.setState({ posts: updatedPosts });
                console.log(response.data);
                console.log(updatedPosts);
            });
    }
    handleChange = event => {
        const name = event.target.name;
        const value = event.target.value;
        const { post } = this.state;
        const newPost = {
            ...post,
            [name]: value
        };
        this.setState({ post: newPost });
        console.log(event.target.value);
        console.log(this.state.post.title);
        console.log(name);
    };

    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const post = {
            post: this.state.post
        };
        const posts = this.state.posts;
        axios
            .post("firebaseURL/posts.json", post)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                this.setState({ post: response.data });
            });
    };

    render() {
        let posts = <p>No posts yet</p>;
        if (this.state.posts) {
            posts = this.state.posts.map(post => {
                return <Post key={post.id} {...post} />;
            });
        }

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <form className="new-post-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label>
                        Post title
                        <input
                            className="title-input"
                            type="text"
                            name="title"
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                        />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        Post content
                        <input
                            className="content-input"
                            type="text"
                            name="content"
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                        />
                    </label>
                    <input className="submit-button" type="submit" value="submit" />
                </form>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Posts />
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
// Render method to run the app

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("id"));
```

And this is a screenshot of my firebase database:
[My Firebase database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gy2ZN.png)

Comment: Getting response and setting the state is not a big problem in your case. Though your response is an object instead of an array it is not so hard to manipulate it and update the state. But, the problem here is your DB shape is not homogenous. There is an object which has a post object, there is one which has an object with an id which has a post object, there is even a weirder nested one :) So, first of all, just figure that out. I don't know Firebase much but after you solved this, getting a response and manipulating it is very easy. There are methods like `Object.keys`.

Comment: Thanks. as I mentioned my post method might have a problem.How should I send data to get that data as an array and not nested?

Comment: So, your main question is related to saving into a Firebase DB. You can change the title according to that and maybe add a `firebase` tag.

Comment: It was not my main question. But I suspected if this is the issue. I added firebase anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is interesting that what I found is rarely mentioned anywhere around it.
This is the entire Posts component:

```
class Posts extends React.Component {
    state = {
        posts: [],
        post: {
            title: "",
            content: ""
        }
    };

    componentWillMount() {
        const { posts } = this.state;
        axios
            .get("firebaseURL/posts.json")
            .then(response => {
            const data = Object.values(response.data);
            this.setState({ posts : data });
            });
    }
    handleChange = event => {
        const name = event.target.name;
        const value = event.target.value;
        const { post } = this.state;
        const newPost = {
            ...post,
            [name]: value
        };
        this.setState({ post: newPost });
        console.log(event.target.value);
        console.log(this.state.post.title);
        console.log(name);
    };

    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const {post} = this.state;
        const {posts} = this.state;
        axios
            .post("firebaseURL/posts.json", post)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
              const newPost = response.data;
                this.setState({ post: response.data });
            });
    };

    render() {
        let posts = <p>No posts yet</p>;
        if (this.state.posts) {
            posts = this.state.posts.map(post => {
                return <Post key={post.id} {...post} />;
            });
        }

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {posts}
                <form className="new-post-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label>
                        Post title
                        <input
                            className="title-input"
                            type="text"
                            name="title"
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                        />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        Post content
                        <input
                            className="content-input"
                            type="text"
                            name="content"
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                        />
                    </label>
                    <input className="submit-button" type="submit" value="submit" />
                </form>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

Actually as I first time read in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50888496/axios-get-request-gets-all-the-data-unless-i-set-state-in-the-then-method-in-w) you should not rely on console.log to see if your posts (or your response data) has been updated. Because in componentDidMount() when you immediately update state you will not see the change in console. So what I did was to display the data that I got from the response using map over the posts and it showed my items as I actually had an array although couldn't see in the console. This is my code for componentDidMount:

```
axios.get("firebaseURL/posts.json").then(response => {
    const data = Object.values(response.data);
    this.setState({
        posts: data
});
```

And show the posts:

```
let posts = <p>No posts yet</p>;
if (this.state.posts) {
    posts = this.state.posts.map(post => {
        return <Post key={post.id} {...post} />;
    });
}
```

And it shows all the posts as expected. Take away is to be careful once woking on componentDidMound and other lifecycle methods as you might not see the updated data in the console inside them but you actually need to use it as it is in the response. The state is updated but you are not able to see it inside that method.

Comment: I had the same problem and Object.values solved it. Thanks!

Comment: Great to hear that.They are very handy in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

Not a database expert, but I believe your database is structured a bit odd and will only cause problems further down the line, especially when it comes to editing/updating a single post. Ideally, it should structured like a `JSON` array:

```
posts: [
  {
    id: "LNO_qS0Y9PjIzGds5PW",
    title: "Example title",
    content: "This is just a test"
  },
  {
    id: "LNOc1vnvA57AB4HkW_i",
    title: "Example title",
    content: "This is just a test"
  },
   ...etc
]
```

instead its structured like a `JSON` object:

```
"posts": {
  "LNO_qS0Y9PjIzGds5PW": {
     "post": {
       "title": "Example title",
       "content": "This is just a test"
     }
   },
   "LNOc1vnvA57AB4HkW_i": {
      "post": {
       "title": "Example title",
       "content": "This is just a test"
     }
   },
   ...etc
}
```

---

Anyway, your project should have a parent `Posts` `container-component` that controls all your state and fetching of data, then it passes down its `state` and class `methods` to component `children`. Then the `children` can update or display the parent's `state` accordingly.

**OR**

You should separate your `Posts` `container-component`, so that it either displays found posts or a "No posts found" component. And then, have your `Posts Form` component be it's own/unshared component whose only function is to show a form and submit it to a DB.

Up to you and what you think fits your needs.

---

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/4x4kxn9qxw (the example below has one `container-component` that shares with many children)

Note: If you change `posts` to an empty array `[]`, instead of `data` in `fetchData()`s `this.setState()` function, you can have the `PostForm` be displayed under the `/posts` route!

ex: `.then(({ data }) => this.setState({ isLoading: false, posts: [] }))`

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import App from "./routes";
import "uikit/dist/css/uikit.min.css";
import "./styles.css";

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**routes/index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "../components/Home";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import Posts from "../containers/Posts";

export default () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/posts" component={Posts} />
        <Route path="/postsform" component={Posts} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

**containers/Posts.js**

```
import isEmpty from "lodash/isEmpty";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import PostsForm from "../components/postsForm";
import ServerError from "../components/serverError";
import ShowPosts from "../components/showPosts";
import Spinner from "../components/spinner";

export default class Posts extends Component {
  state = {
    content: "",
    error: "",
    isLoading: true,
    posts: [],
    title: ""
  };

  componentDidUpdate = (prevProps, prevState) => {
    // check if URL has changed from "/posts" to "/postsform" or vice-versa
    if (this.props.location.pathname !== prevProps.location.pathname) {
      // if so, check the location
      this.setState({ isLoading: true }, () => this.checkLocation());
    }
  };

  componentDidMount = () => this.checkLocation();

  checkLocation = () => {
    // if the location is "/posts" ...
    this.props.location.pathname === "/posts"
      ? this.fetchData() // then fetch data
      : this.setState({  // otherwise, clear state
          content: "",
          error: "",
          isLoading: false,
          posts: [],
          title: ""
        });
  };

  // fetches posts from DB and stores it in React state
  fetchData = () => {
    axios
      .get("firebaseURL/posts.json")
      .then(({ data }) => this.setState({ isLoading: false, posts: data }))
      .catch(err => this.setState({ error: err.toString() }));
  };

  // handles postsForm input changes { content: value , title: value }
  handleChange = e => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  // handles postsForm form submission
  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { content, title } = this.state;

    alert(`Sumbitted values: ${title} - ${content}`);

   /* axios.post("firebaseURL/posts.json", { post: { title, content }})
        .then(({data}) => this.setState({ content: "", posts: data, title: "" }))
        .catch(err => this.setState({ error: err.toString() }))
   */
  };

  // the below simply returns an if/else chain using the ternary operator
  render = () => (
    this.state.isLoading // if isLoading is true...
      ? <Spinner />  // show a spinner
      : this.state.error  // otherwise if there's a server error...
         ? <ServerError {...this.state} />  // show the error
         : isEmpty(this.state.posts) // otherwise, if posts array is still empty..
            ? <PostsForm  // show the postForm
                {...this.state}
                handleChange={this.handleChange}
                handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
              />
            : <ShowPosts {...this.state} /> // otherwise, display found posts!
  );
}
```

**components/postsForm.js**

```
import React from "react";

export default ({ content, handleSubmit, handleChange, title }) => (
  <form
    style={{ padding: "0 30px", width: 500 }}
    className="new-post-form"
    onSubmit={handleSubmit}
  >
    <label>
      Post title
      <input
        style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}
        className="uk-input"
        type="text"
        name="title"
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="Enter post title..."
        value={title}
      />
    </label>
    <label>
      Post content
      <input
        style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}
        className="uk-input"
        type="text"
        name="content"
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="Enter post..."
        value={content}
      />
    </label>
    <button 
      disabled={!title || !content}
      className="uk-button uk-button-primary" 
      type="submit"
    >
      Submit
    </button>
  </form>
);
```

**components/showPosts.js**

```
import map from "lodash/map";
import React from "react";

export default ({ posts }) => (
  <div className="posts">
    {map(posts, ({ post: { content, title } }, key) => (
      <div key={key} className="post">
        <h2 className="post-title">{title}</h2>
        <hr />
        <p className="post-content">{content}</p>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

**components/serverError.js**

```
import React from "react";

export default ({ err }) => (
  <div style={{ color: "red", padding: 20 }}>
    <i style={{ marginRight: 5 }} className="fas fa-exclamation-circle" /> {err}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Thanks for this.
In my handle submit function I have changed the post object to this:

const post = {
   title: this.state.post.title,
   content: this.state.post.content
  };

And now I have added this in my promise:
const updatedPosts = Object.values(data);

I get an array like this:
0:
{content: "tested", title: "tested again"}
1:
{content: "test", title: "test"}
2:
{content: "test", title: "test"}


How an I get an array out of this to use? I have tried map and Object.values and Object.keys but no luck. I want only the values not the keys.

Comment: I need this as one single array:
[{content: "tested", title: "tested again"} ,{content: "test", title: "test"} , {content: "test", title: "test"}]
Any ideas?

Comment: Use the `spread` operator inside of an array `[ ]`. So it'd be `const updatedPosts = [ ...data ]`. Ideally, you'll want a unique id attached to each individual post. That way, you can update by id AND in the `showPosts`'s `map` function, replace `key={key}` to `key={id}`!

Comment: I did that but I cannot update my state here so that I can use it inside the showPosts. The this.setState({ posts : updatedPosts });  is not populating posts with data and posts showing an empty array!

Comment: Fork my codesandbox and update it with the code you're trying to implement, then post the link to your forked codesandbox.

Comment: Thank you for that but I won't do that as I want my code to be fixed. Most of it is right. I just need to find out what is wrong with not updating the state. setState can be called immediately in componentDidMount and should work here. I need someone to help me on this. It is a basic application. Thanks.